# A Database Error Occurred How to submit same name Input field using jQuery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new to stackoverflow. So, forgive me for anything wrong. I am not so expert in programming area.

I am trying to build an small application using Codeigniter. I do not not how to pass dynamic same input field value using jQuery to Codeigniter controller to model. I am using this jQuery plugin to make dynamic input field.

For test purpose, I have pasted same html input code more than 3times.

Error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2) VALUES ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('',' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `products` (0, 1, 2) VALUES ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','',''), ('','','')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/store_management/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

My code:

```
function add_product($params)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('products',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}



     function add()
{   
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)     
    {   
             $params = array(
            'code_number' => $this->input->post('code_number'),
            'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
            'brand_name' => $this->input->post('brand_name'),
            'product_category' => $this->input->post('product_category'),
            'cost_price' => $this->input->post('cost_price'),
            'selling_price' => $this->input->post('selling_price'),
            'initial_stock' => $this->input->post('initial_stock'),
        );

        $product_id = $this->Product_model->add_product($params);
        redirect('product/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('product/add');
    }
}


<?php echo form_open( 'product/add',array( "class"=>"form-horizontal","id"=>"dynamic")); ?>
<table>
  <tbody id="itemlist">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm text-right" name="code_number[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('code_number'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="brand_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('brand_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_category[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_category'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="cost_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('cost_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="selling_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('selling_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="initial_stock[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('initial_stock'); ?>">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn-remove btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm text-right" name="code_number[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('code_number'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="brand_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('brand_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_category[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_category'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="cost_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('cost_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="selling_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('selling_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="initial_stock[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('initial_stock'); ?>">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn-remove btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm text-right" name="code_number[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('code_number'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="brand_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('brand_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_category[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_category'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="cost_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('cost_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="selling_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('selling_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="initial_stock[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('initial_stock'); ?>">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn-remove btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm text-right" name="code_number[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('code_number'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="brand_name[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('brand_name'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="product_category[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('product_category'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="cost_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('cost_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="selling_price[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('selling_price'); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="initial_stock[]" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('initial_stock'); ?>">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn-remove btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am using this plugin to create dynamic input fields http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx2/dynamic_form.html

Comment: I am trying to make like this one http://creativeitem.com/demo/bijoy/index.php?/admin/purchase_order_add

Comment: Don't add comments to your question, you can use the `edit` button above for editing your question. Also check this page for some guidelines on how to ask a question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This doesnt seem like dynamic inputs since ur controller has hard-coded the array which does not seem like what u need at all anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ur already using Jquery according to ur question you should search up Ajax too. It's a nice way of posting data over ajax and will not have to refresh the page. below is a small example code for posting data to your controller.

```
var postData = {
    product_name1: $("#product_name1").val()
}

$.post( "/route/to/post/to", { postData  }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data); // Response data
}, "json");
```

You just got to build up the above array to your liking and change the route it should post to accordingly. Once you've done that you should be ready to go.

[AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)